# Interim analyses without any stopping rules

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, sequential-analysis

I've got some questions about interim analysis rules.

Do I need to make alpha/beta corrections in the following situation:

- One interim analysis is planned in the study
- The interim analysis is needed for sample size re-estimation only.
- I don't need to stop the study early
- $H_o$ or $H_a$ are not tested at the interim analysis
- Need to estimate means and standard deviations and re-estimate sample size.

Should I use any alpha/beta corrections? Could you please explain the point or give some links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this is some form of randomized controlled trial and that there is no chance that the unblinded group/data monitoring committee would decide to reject $H_0$ after seeing the interim results (some authors argue to always add an adjustment to give them a criterion and to always pay some penalty for all interim analyses). The main question would be the exact nature of the sample size re-estimation. There are forms of blinded sample size re-estimation that do not need an adjusted in order to control the type I error rate, but unblinded sample size re-estimation e.g. when it takes into account the group means typically results in a need for adjustment in order to control the type I error rate.

One methodology that allows to adjust for this would be adaptive design methods (e.g. p-value combination approaches) and there is an extensive literature on this. A good starting point for reading up on the topic could be: Vandemeulebroecke, Marc. "Group sequential and adaptive designs–a review of basic concepts and points of discussion." Biometrical Journal 50.4 (2008): 541-557.

Note that you will not necessarily have e.g. unbiased estimates, even if your analysis approach controls the type I error rate.

Comment: Dear Björn, Many thanks for answer!

You are right, this is the randomized controlled trial (oncology non-inferiority). And if we had the possibility to make it blind the study would be blind, but it is impossible.
Interim is needed because of a small amount of information about the effect for sample-size calculation.
Do you know any examples when only Biostatistician is blinded?

When we test the Ho we need to preserve the overall type I error, I understand that when we calculate the power or SS we need to adjust type II error, but should I really have to use all adjustments in my case?

Comment: Yes, from everything you have said, an adjustment should be needed. If the adjustment were by a rule that does not use group means but rather information that would be available in a blinded trial, then this might be different. Once you use the observed means/effects in each group, it is close to impossible to not need an adjustment. If the trial is not blinded, then any rule that is planned to only use blinded information would have to be very clearly pre-specified (otherwise there would always be the suspicion that the unblinded group means were used, after all, to "manipulate" the study).